# Working With Multiple Timers in C# Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, timer, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to perform 3 Database Related operations in One Hour.

1: Checking for Specific Time On Every One Minute

2: Updating Specific Records After Every 15 Minutes

3: Updating Specific Records After Every 60 Minutes

Till 15 Minute everything is Ok... But on 15 Minutes 2 timers has to access database at the same time. So that's why it's showing me error. `Connection is already Open`. Now After 60 Minutes all three Timer are accessing database at the same time so that's why it will show message again `Connection is Already Open`. After 60 Minutes everything is normal till 15 Minutes.But when next 15 Minutes will come. Message will be visible again and so on. Here is Timer

Timer1:

```
    _Timer = new Timer();
    this._Timer.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 1;
    this._Timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this._Timer_Tick);
    _Timer.Enabled = true;
```

Here is _Timer_Tick Method

```
  CheckConnnectionStatus();
  string cGroupQuery = "select value from settings where id=1 ";

        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(cGroupQuery, sqlConnection);
            sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (sqlDataReader.Read())
            {
                string value= sqlDataReader[0].ToString();

                if (value== "True")
                {
                    Library.WriteErrorLog("System State Done Successfully");
                    TakeSystemState();
                    UpdateSystemState();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Library.WriteErrorLog(exp.Message.ToString() + " | Exception in CheckPrayerTime");
        }
        finally
        {
            CheckConnnectionStatus();
        }
```

Timer2:

```
    _Timer02 = new Timer();
    this._Timer02.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 15;
    this._Timer02.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this._Timer02_Tick);
    _Timer02.Enabled = true;
```

Timer3:

```
    _Timer03 = new Timer();
    this._Timer03.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 60;
    this._Timer03.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this._Timer03_Tick);
    _Timer03.Enabled = true;
```

Can anyone guide me best approach to perform these three operations in Timer in Web Service

I am using Sql Server 2008R2 Express Edition

Thanks

Comment: Could you share the implementation of the `_Timer_Tick` method with us?

Comment: @botond.botos, yeah sure. Please check edited post now

Comment: Why did you choose to put these database operations inside a web service? Implementing it as a windows service seems to be more adequate. Or you could implement it as a simple console application which gets called by a task scheduler, so you don't have to worry about the `Timer` part at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the `SqlConnection.Open()` method throws an `InvalidOperationException` if the connection is already open. For more details, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx

As a solution, you could create a new `SqlConnection` object in each of your `Timer` event handler methods and `Dispose()` it once you are done with the processing.

It is a good practice, to place the newly created `SqlConnection` object in a `using` statement, so that the connection will be released even if an exception was thrown:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    conn.Open();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: May be this problem is coming because i am using one object to access database for all timers ?. `sqlConnection`

Comment: So should i use different object for all three timers ? for timer1-> sqlCon for timer2->sqlCon02 for timer3->sqlCon03 ??

Comment: Exactly, I suggest creating new instances in each of your `Timer` handler methods. These instance can be stored in a local variable, so you don't have to give different names for them.